# JTable does not display UTF-8 chars when launched from JAR

Tags: java, swing, encoding, jar, jtable

When I launch the JAR file that I build, JTable does not display UTF-8. When I launch it inside IntelliJ IDEA, it does display correctly.

I have a couple of ideas but cannot find a way to debug it. First of all, the table data is being serialised, maybe there is something I don't know about it and I need to specify somewhere that it is UTF-8?

Secondly, maybe I need to specify somewhere the encoding where I create and populate the JTable as GUI element? I am adding code pieces for both

The code that I use for saving and retrieving data is here:

```
 private void deserialiseStatsData(){
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tabledata.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        tableData = (TableData) ois.readObject();
        fis.close();
        ois.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        tableData = new TableData();
    }
}
private void serialiseStatsData(){
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("tabledata.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(tableData);
        oos.close();
        fos.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Code for creating and populating the table:

```
 private void createUIComponents() {
        String headers[] = {"Exercise", "Did Succeed?", "Times Failed Before 1st Success",
                "Accuracy (%), ", "Checked Result Before Succeeding"};
        TableData dataTable = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("tabledata.ser");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            dataTable = (TableData) ois.readObject();
            fis.close();
            ois.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Object[][] data;


        int rows = dataTable.getRows();
        int cols = headers.length;
        data = new Object[rows][cols];
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
            data[j][0] = dataTable.getLine(j).getExercise();
            data[j][1] = dataTable.getLine(j).isSuccess();
            data[j][2] = dataTable.getLine(j).getNoOfFails();
            data[j][3] = dataTable.getLine(j).getPercentage();
            data[j][4] = dataTable.getLine(j).isAnswerCheckBeforeSuccess();
        }

        table = new JTable(data, headers);
    }
```

What I have tried:

1. Added lines to VM Options:

   -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8

   -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
2. Changed encoding in Settings -> File Encodings to UTF-8

At this point, I don't know what else I could do.

Edited:
I get stuff like this in JTable:

[image]

When I should get stuff like this:

[image]

Char list which does not display:

- union = '\u222A';

  intersection = '\u2229';

  product = '\u2A2F';

  difference = '\u2216';

  infinity = '\u221E';

  belongsTo = '\u2208';

  weakSubset = '\u2286';

  properSubset = '\u2282';

Comment: What do you mean by "does not display UTF-8"  -  what's happening, do you get an error or unexpected output or what

Comment: @Joni please see the attached pictures. These are of two different data objects. Though, you should be able to see that mathematical set operator symbols are not displayed correctly.

Comment: Does the `TableData` class have some kind of custom serialization logic?

Comment: @Joni Not really, TableData just implements Serializable, holds data in  ArrayList<SingleTableLine> data and custom rules for addTableLine().   SingleTableLine also implements Serializable, holds simple stuff like String for the name of exercise, bool, bool, int, int.

Comment: The default serialization does not introduce bugs like this so there must be something more going on. Can you use a debugger to find out at what points the strings get corrupted? It could be before they are written to the file, or it could be after they have been read.

Comment: @Joni, I am not sure how that would be possible. When I run the program from IDE, I get everything looking well. When I compile a JAR and run it from my win10, it gives these weird characters

Comment: Do you use the same tabledata.ser file when you run from IDE and as an independent program? Is there anything that could maybe modify or overwrite that file?